# 1 way SSL with MQIPT and tomcat docker

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq, tomcat8, spring-jms

I am trying to connect to MQIPT which is having 1 way SSL enabled. Below is my spring configuration

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <ref bean="mqQueueConnectionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mqQueueConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
        <property name="hostName" value="xx.xx.xx.xx" />
        <property name="port" value="xxxx" />
        <property name="queueManager" value="QM" />
        <property name="transportType" value="1" />
        <property name="channel" value="SSL.CHNL" />
        <property name="SSLCipherSuite" value="SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="destination" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="SANDBOX_Q" />
        <property name="baseQueueManagerName">
            <value>QM</value>
        </property>
        <property name="baseQueueName">
            <value>QUEUE</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I added the certs to truststore and set the flag -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false in tomcat start up. In the MQIPT ciphersuite is set as SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA. I am getting the below error

```
MQ Exception:: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'. .... Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2400' ('MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE').
```

I am using JDK 8 and MQ client jars version 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an Oracle JRE, then you need to specify the SSLCipherSuite per the table in the IBM MQ V8 Knowledge Center page "[SSL/TLS CipherSpecs and CipherSuites in IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q113220_.htm)"

```
CipherSpec                  |Equivalent CipherSuite (IBM JRE)|Equivalent CipherSuite (Oracle JRE)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA|  SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  |TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

Based on the above, if MQIPT which uses the IBM JRE is specifying `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`, that means the SVRCONN channel on the queue manager should be specifying `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` and an Oracle JRE with `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` should be specifying `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` as well.

Summary, change your Spring configuration to:

```
<property name="SSLCipherSuite" value="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"/>
```

Comment: @AnilBhaskaran please confirm you are using Oracle JRE.  Do you see any errors in the logs for MQIPT when you get the spring error?  What specific v8 version are you using?  The useIBMCipherMappings settings was introduced in 8.0.0.2.

Comment: I don't have access to MQIPT logs. Will check that. I am using open-jdk 8 wiith tomcat / docker. So you see any challenge with open jdk?

Comment: I have not had experiance with it working but based on the documentation IBM refers to "IBM JRE" and "Oracle JRE".  It may work but may not be something tested/supported by IBM.  The version I'm asking about is the jar files you mention "MQ client jars version 8", what specific version is the jar file from.  One Linux you can run a command like the following against one of the com.ibm.*.jar files `unzip -p com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep -i Implementation-Version`.

Comment: The version of ibm client jars is 8.0.0.7

Comment: @AnilBhaskaran Thank you, that version supports `useIBMCipherMappings`. Which specific version of OpenJDK are you using? Can you try it with either Oracle JRE or IBM JRE to see if you have the same issue?  I searched and it appears that OpenJDK 8 should support TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA.

Comment: Its working. The problem was because of the jar. i was using mqjms,jmqi and mq jars. Instead I used allclient.jar and it started working with the above mentioned.  @JoshMc

Comment: @AnilBhaskaran Even if using separate jar files it should work if they were from a version of MQ which supports the `useIBMCipherMappings` setting and the CipherSpec that you were using.  Check each of the jar files you previously specified with a command like `unzip -p com.ibm.___.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep -i Implementation-Version` I think you may find one or more of them were not from 8.0.0.7 as you thought.  I appreciate the accept.  Upvotes welcome as well :)